# Transactional, in-memory, object/key/value storage library?

Tags: c++, database, key-value

I have a C++ application whose in-memory data set consists of a set of objects, each of which has a key/value set attached. Objects and keys are referred to by an int id, and values are always instances of a single class. Key ids are unique in an object, objects ids are unique in the universe.

This is *almost* a `map<pair<int, int>, value>` except that I have the additional requirement that I need to be able to enumerate the keys attached to a particular object. And it all needs to be transactional, so I can roll back changes if things go wrong.

This all strikes me as being a totally standard problem for which I should be able to get off-the-shelf code, but I've been unable to find anything. Can anyone:

(a) tell me what this problem is actually called, so I know what to look for;

(b) suggest any code I should look at.

Note that I want this to be an in-memory data store only, so NoSQL approaches like Berkeley DB aren't suitable --- I don't want to keep reading and writing value objects (which are moderately complex).

So far I've found either simple approaches that don't do transactions (like boost_multi_index, or even just nested STL maps), or complex approaches using persistent storage, but nothing in between. I could implement my own transactional layer on top of basic storage, but to be honest, I'd rather not.

What am I missing?

**Edit**: well, nobody appears to have been able to suggest one; so I wrote my own. It is surprisingly fiddly but not actually very much code. Right now it's just a template class using nested maps for storage but I'm considering changing to using boost::multi_index_container instead for simplicity. It's not polished and probably riddled with bugs but if anyone thinks they can use it, let me know.

**More Edit**: for reference, it turns out that the Googleable name for what I'm looking for is a **entity/attribute/value database (EAV)**.

Comment: Look at SQLite with the :memory: pseudo-DB

Comment: This still requires me to serialise/deserialise my values when I access them. I want to use a local data store so that my values are just pointers to C++ objects, avoiding the I/O overhead.

Comment: I don't quite get it. In a database, you use transactions so as not to end up with a partially-successful operation, or another client seeing an inconsistent state due to such an operation. Since you are aiming at a purely in-memory map, there are no complex, multi-step operations that you might want to roll back. If you wrap access in mutexes, you're thread-safe. What else do you want to do that such a mutex-protected std::map is not sufficient?

Comment: I want to be able to get half-way through a mutation of the database, reach an error condition, and then back out all the changes that have happened so far so the database remains consistent. Error conditions will arise if the user asks my program to change an object in a way that's not allowed. I'd really don't want to have to go through a separate validation stage before each mutation.

Comment: @David: is it supposed to be multi-threaded ?

Comment: I think [hamsterdb](http://hamsterdb.com) could work for you but the website seems to be dead right now. Here's the [freshmeat project page](http://freshmeat.net/projects/hamsterdb).

Comment: SQLite is an **embedded** DB (no server process), and with `:memory:` it becomes also an in-memory DB. So where doesn't it meet your requirements?

Comment: @David: so why can't you just store pointers (as ints) in an in-memory SQLite db? Also, @Mattieu's question is pretty important: is this intended for multithreading, or do you just need rollback capability with no consideration for thread safety?

Comment: My app is single-threaded (a server which processes network requests serially), so no, I don't need thread safety. And storing pointers in an SQLite database is... utterly evil, but plausibly so. Unfortunately my objects are mutable so this won't help; I need to roll back the data values as well ('just pointers to C++ objects' was an oversimplification, sorry).

Comment: HamsterDB looks very intriguing, but it's *still* a database solution which requires marshalling of data on access, which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are really after is an exception safe container.

Read these:
http://www.boost.org/community/exception_safety.html
http://lmzr.perso.neuf.fr/attic/Exception_Safe_Generic_Containers.pdf
http://www.drdobbs.com/184401771;jsessionid=TTP1SXYYVJZPLQE1GHPCKH4ATMY32JVN

Your problem quickly reduces to ensuring specific exception guarantees in the stored object's constructor, copy constructor, assignment operator and so on.
If this does not happen then it is likely you have not designed the object types with enough care to separation of concerns.

Comment: Why? Due to the fact that the "rollback" concept you seek is the strong guarantee. ◦The basic guarantee: that the invariants of the component are preserved, and no resources are leaked.
◦The strong guarantee: that the operation has either completed successfully or thrown an exception, leaving the program state exactly as it was before the operation started.
◦The no-throw guarantee: that the operation will not throw an exception.

Comment: yep, well spotted. It sounds like the OP's "transaction" requirement is really better expressed as the strong exception safety guarantee. (Unless thread safety is added to the mix, then genuine ACI(D)-like transactions would be more suitable)

Comment: Do exception safe containers allow rollback across multiple mutations? I need the ability to wrap my entire app's business logic in a transaction so I can either commit or roll it back atomically, rather than individual low-level operations on the container. But I am encouraged that my existing home-made code appears to use the same logic described by the Dr.Dobbs article; thanks for the link.

Comment: I did wonder whether you had left out the need for multiple object modifications. The recommended technique is to copy (the whole container)/modify/swap. That is however not compatible with multithreaded code. That would require the full locking mechanism e.g. lock/modify/unlock

Comment: Then there is this thesis which describes a larger piece of the problem space. "A Software Transactional Memory Library for C++" http://www.diku.dk/forskning/performance-engineering/Kasper/thesis.pdf and it becomes clear that you're tackling a BIG problem. The issue, as is now apparent, is granularity of updates. That begs the question, can you redesign your objects so that they contain ALL their state or does the architecture of your app require arbitrary mutating Relationships?

Comment: Ooh, *very* interesting --- and pretty much exactly what I want. Shame he doesn't seem to have gotten around to releasing the code... some of the references are interesting; LibLTX doesn't work on ARM; DracoSTM has morphed into TBoost.STM and appears not to be in a usable state (in flux, no documentation, no examples); RSTM even less so. Sigh. These things seem fated to become abandoned research projects. anyone know any more?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [Redis](http://redis.io)?  It's a data structure server so you can use a map structure and easily enumerate the keys (see the [hash families of commands](http://redis.io/commands#hash))attached to an object.  It supports [transactions](http://redis.io/commands#transactions) as well.

I guess the downside is that I'm not sure how easy it is to package as a library.

Comment: I did look at Redis --- unfortunately it's not an in-memory database, so I still get I/O overhead when serialising/deserialising my values.

Comment: @David - I studied Redis extensively for some project (didn't choose it after all), and as far as I remember it **is** an in-memory DB. It has an option of logging your updates so that the state of your DB can be restored after restart. This logging is configurable (e.g. every 1 min, or every N updates), or can be turned off completely.

Comment: Yes, but redis still stores all its data in an external server process --- so from my app's perspective I still have all the I/O overhead of serialising and deserialising my objects from the data store, which I would like to avoid. Ideally I just want direct pointer access to C++ objects.

Answer (score -1):

LMDB would handle this. You could use it with a file on tmpfs to guarantee that all operations are in-memory only, or use it on a plain ext3/ext4 filesystem with an extremely long commit time to avoid changes ever being written to disk. It's fully transactional and uses a memory-mapped file; if your filesystem cache writeback time is set long enough and you run it with async commits, then your changes will only exist in RAM and never flush to disk.
It can do zero-copy reads and writes; you can write objects with minimal serialization and reference them with zero deserialization.